# Display content of "B2" according to what is selected from "A2" from a dropdown list

Tags: excel

I have two `columns` that I named X and Y, respectively. `Column x` has numbers from 1 to 10, and adjacent to them, letters from "a" to "j". `Column y` follows the same logic, but with roman numerals and letters from "K to T".

I have a dropdown list for x and another for y. Beside each dropdown list, I want to display what is adjacent to the selected number/numeral. Ie, if I select "6" from `column x`, it'll display"f" and if I select "VII", it will display "R".

I made a screenshot with what I want to do, but the numbers in red were put manually.

[image]

Comment: Looks like `VLOOKUP` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

As cybernetic.nomad said, VLOOKUP is the best solution here. Try putting `vlookup(G2;A2:B11;2;0)` in H2 cell. Same solution applies for the other column.